# How do I prevent a custom exception from being raised in Python?

Tags: python, exception, python-class

I've been messing around with custom Exceptions but I want to find out how it can prevent itself from being raised depending on whether a variable is there.

for eg.

```py
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, var):
        if var == "prevent":
            # Stop exception from being raised


raise MyError("prevent")
```

Comment: The `MyError` class is instantiated *after* the error has been raised. There is no way you can prevent the error from being raised at this point.

Comment: What's the point of `raise MyError("prevent")` anyway? If you know that you want to prevent the error (because you're going to pass `"prevent"` to its constructor) then don't raise it in the first place.

Comment: Actually, `MyError("prevent")` needs to be evaluated before it can be raised -- it's just as incorrect to suppose that the exception is instantiated *after* being raised as it is to suppose that you can prevent it from being raised after it's already happened.  :)  It is therefore technically possible to prevent the exception from being raised while its instantiation is still in progress...

Comment: @Samwise I think the point here is that `MyError` isn't instantiated until after the decision has been made (by executing the `raise` statement) to raise *an* error. Code that explicitly instantiates an exception *before* executing a `raise` statement is rare.

Comment: Regardless of the rarity of the situation, I remain technically correct (the best kind of correct).

Answer (score 1):

You can interrupt any control flow (including one that is itself in the act of initializing and raising an exception) by raising an exception, which makes it technically possible to prevent a specific exception from being raised *within its own init* by having the init raise a *different* exception:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, var):
...         if var == "prevent":
...             raise ValueError("unacceptable to raise MyError right now")
...
>>> try:
...     raise MyError("prevent")
... except MyError:
...     print("UNACCEPTABLE!")
... except ValueError:
...     print("okie dokie")
...
okie dokie
```

A more typical pattern, as others have suggested, would be to do the check *before* you raise the exception (so you can avoid raising any exception at all).  It's perfectly reasonable to put this in a function that wraps the exception, e.g.:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     pass
...
>>> def maybe_raise_myerror(var):
...     if var != "prevent":
...         raise MyError
...
>>> maybe_raise_myerror("prevent")
>>> maybe_raise_myerror("foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in maybe_raise_myerror
__main__.MyError
```

One use of this pattern would be a set of validators -- you have functions that conditionally raise different exceptions that correspond to different validation errors, and you call them all in a sequence under a single `try` block that will handle the first error that gets raised.

Comment: If you think the problem is pointless, downvote the question; if you can think of a better solution (namely a way to prevent an exception from being raised *within the code of the Exception class itself*) submit your own answer!  :)

Comment: Can I also say that things are pointless without downvoting anybody? This is clearly a *"it's not stupid if it works"* situation. Your code works, but I don't get which problem it solves. If you expect a situation and don't want it to throw an exception, then ... not throwing an exception seems like a better way of resolving it than throwing *another* exception from the constructor of the exception that you just threw, just so you can catch in the same block of code that threw it. But maybe that's just me an this is normal. ;)

Comment: The example is obviously contrived, but there are situations where it's useful (or unavoidable!) to raise an exception during the construction of another exception, so there's value in understanding how the control flow works in that situation.

Comment: Alright. As an academic example for the fact that exceptions are classes, that constructors can throw, and that exception handling code is just code, it's fine. :)